# Typescript not see nodejs globals

Tags: node.js, typescript

I was using Typescript 1.8 with typings, but i decided to upgrade to typescript 2.8 with @types. I downloaded @types/node, but console show errors:

```
 error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
```

The structure of my project is the following:

```
node_modules
src >
  client
  server > 
     tsconfig.ts
```

tsconfig.ts:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
        "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "server",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": [
      "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Adding `"types": ["node"]` not help

Comment: ```"target": "es6"```, so try import syntax instead...

Comment: @valery.sntx it doesn't see other nodejs globals, like proccess

Answer (score 0):

Based on your directory structure, it looks like the path for the `typeRoots` option is incorrect - it should be a relative path from your tsconfig file. Your `node_modules` directory is 2 levels higher than the location of your tsconfig, so your type roots should be:

```
"../../node_modules/@types"
```

Full tsconfig:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
        "../../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "server",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": [
      "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```